# need consult using memory allocation TCMalloc replaces the default Glibc in MySQL

Tags: mysql, tcmalloc

Please consult the experienced pro using memory allocation
TCMalloc replaces the default Glibc in MySQL.
What are the disadvantages of TCMalloc? Is it compatible with all versions of MySQL 8.0
Are not?
because we want to deploy TCMalloc on multiple versions of MySQL server in product environment
Thanks!

I have deployed on test environment with good results, but not enough version MySQL server, and don't know if TCMalloc works with all versions of MySQL 8.0?